# Documentum D2 - Class type interface com.emc.d2fs.dctm.content.ID2Content not found

Tags: documentum, documentum-d2

On Logging to Documentum D2 with Life Science Module installed it shows a Failure dialog with

> Class type interface  com.emc.d2fs.dctm.content.ID2 Content not found

[image]

Am I missing any component of D2 or Life Science module for this to work